# Detect if mbstring is enabled or not from PHP script

Tags: php, mbstring

How can I check if the mbstring extension is loaded in a php script?

Answer (score 42):

Use `if (extension_loaded('mbstring')) { /* loaded */ }`

See [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php).

Answer (score 17):

Also useful:

`php -i | grep mbstring`

Output:

```
/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
Multibyte decoding support using mbstring => enabled
mbstring
mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.
mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.http_input => no value => no value
mbstring.http_output => no value => no value
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
mbstring.regex_retry_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
mbstring.regex_stack_limit => 100000 => 100000
mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value
```

Answer (score 16):

From terminal/console, go in PHP CLI mode and echo the command as below,

```
$ php -a

php > echo extension_loaded('mbstring');
1
```

It will return 1 if mbstring is loaded as an extension otherwise null

Answer (score 14):

Run this code in php file --

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

[image: mbstring]

Comment: You forgot mention which parameter it is,.

Answer (score 3):

Use the extension_loaded class:

```
extension_loaded('mbstring');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it through phpinfo().

Search for the string "mbstring" in phpinfo page. If it is present means then mbstring is enabled or it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you cannot find mbstring in phpinfo();    
change extension_dir = "ext" to  extension_dir = "c:/php/ext" 
in c:\php\php.ini file
```

Comment: Can you add a little explanation?